# Magento 2 - How to remove "Save" button in inline of grid customers index admin page?

Tags: magento2, customer, adminhtml, grid-layout, inline

How to remove "Save" button in inline of grid customers index admin page ?

[image]

Anyone know anything, can show me, pls!

Comment: Do you just want to hide/remove the button, or do you also want to change functionality and or behaviour? How would you save after you remove the button?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the button, I want remove it b/c I want to custom default component of magento.